# Video background for android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a single video playing in the background of my application, so that when any new activity is pushed on the stack, it will have a transparent background so that the application background video is all the time visible.

How would I accomplish this, without any risk of the activity containing the video gets destroyed at any stage?

Comment: What is your goin to achieve using transparent activity here ?

Comment: I want to have the same video playing in the background throughout the lifetime of the app, and that this will be visible through any additional activity which is pushed on the stack

Comment: Use one activity and just excange fragments. and videoView would be at activity root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

You will have to implement this as a single activity, possibly using fragments to handle your changing content. Even then, the user can always exit this activity.

Bear in mind that this will not work well except on devices offering 2D graphic hardware acceleration. That is possible on Android 3.0+ devices when you request hardware acceleration in the manifest. On Android 1.x and 2.x devices, this will likely perform very poorly.